# Splitting of $k[[x_1,...,x_n]]\to \bar k [[x_1,...,x_n]]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, extension-field, formal-power-series, regular-rings

Let $k$ be a field, of positive characteristic, with algebraic closure $\bar k$. Then, is it true that for every integer $n\ge 1$, the inclusion map $k[[x_1,...,x_n]]\to \bar k [[x_1,...,x_n]]$ splits as a map of $k[[x_1,...,x_n]]$-modules?

Comment: What do you mean by "splits" here? Splits as a map of modules? Over which ring?

Comment: @AlexKruckman: splits as a map of $k[[x_1,...,x_n]]$-modules

Comment: $\overline{k} = k\oplus V$ as $k$-vector space and $\overline{k}[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]]=k[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]]\oplus V[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]]$ as $k[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]]$-module (the meaning of $V[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]]$ is clear I hope, the power series whose coefficients are taken in $V$)